# Design flaw concerning the location of a notification box

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, voting, notifications

When voting on a comment, one can only up-vote once every 5 seconds. Try to vote  more often than that, and you'll get a yellow box telling informing you of this policy. However, the box is placed near the last comment **which can be invisible to you.**

I think that the box should appear right over the comment you are trying to up-vote, since that comment should be visible.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't call it a design flaw, just a plain old bug – this wasn't by design. You're absolutely right, the popup should appear where you clicked (it used to be that way; this was a regression).  Fixed in the next build; thanks!

Comment: I was being polite.